# Wrapping Business Logic In Extension Methods For POCOs

Tags: c#, design-patterns, extension-method

I have recently stumbled upon a use case of extension methods and wanted to gather some design thoughts.

The problem:
A IEnumerable of a POCO and within that list there should exist a POCO that satisfies a condition say `POCO.IsTheRightOne == true`.

You could write and extension class for this query

```cs
public static class POCOExtensions
{
   public static bool GetIsTheRightPOCO(this List<POCO> source){
      return source.Single(poco => poco.IsTheRightOne == true).UsefulProperty;
   }

}
```

Now this to me is clean. It is easily testable, their is no need for a utils or helper class to be in the middle, the logic is encapsulated, and no side effects or other classes are needed.

Another way I could go about this is create a POCOList class and wrap the behavior in that and then you would get the same benefits and still have the ability to override behavior if needed. But since this is a poco class chances of me needing that are pretty slim.

Something about this pattern though just doesn't sit right with me. I feel like I'm paying a unseen cost. What other drawbacks to this design am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods are Bad(tm)

1. Static methods cant be mocked out

   Sure you can test this method, but can you unit test something that uses it?
2. Extension methods are hard to find.

   Unless you know the namespace and package to include for this method you have no way to find it. As opposed to a method on the Poco itself or a service for the over all operation.
3. It has all the downsides of a helper library.

   What you have here is a orphaned helper method, It's hard to name, it's hard to group up with the data or other object that need it, its hard to know what references it and what will break if you change it.

Instead, I would suggest this should be a private method on a service class which does whatever larger operation you are performing with your Pocos. That encapsulates it with other methods and data related to the process and gives you a nice `DoWhateverWithPocosService()` class which can be interfaced and mocked as required.

Comment: Regarding #1, it depends on the static method. If the method is idempotent, then yes, you can write unit tests for things that call the static method. Regarding #2: it depends. If the extension methods are in the same namespace as the type it extends, then they are just as easy to find. The OP's use case is a little complicated because the proposed method extends `List<T>`, so you have two types requiring `using` statements before you can discover the method. But #3 is spot on.

Comment: #1 if you are being strict your unit test wants to call a mocked version, which the static doesn't allow. #2 if you use the same namespace you are going to collide with other extension methods

Comment: Mocking is not a requirement for "strict" unit testing. A "unit" of behavior is not a well-defined term, but typically you mock behavior that modifies or reads from external state. If the logic is simple and idempotent, why complicate your test with a mock? And I wouldn't worry about name collisions for domain-specific extension methods. Sure it is a risk, but it is a judgement call whether or not a naming collision is likely.

Comment: I guess the question is do you _know_ the call doesn't have side effects. If its just some pure function obvs its going to be fine, but if its some random library extension method? Same with the namespaces, sure if its all your code then you aren't going to worry, but If you are publishing services.AddWebAuthentication(config) ?

Comment: 1. Pure function and writing the unit tests was very easy. I'm trying to get away from mocking if I can as I find it's probably an indicator of a deeper problem for the level our code is at.
2. Same namespace as the poco and file is right next to the poco so kept it clean on finding them

Comment: For 3. It does feel isolated or orphaned. It only ever operates on itself so it shouldn't need to be grouped up with anything else. I think I need to read a bit more on the reach of extension methods to get the point fully here. Since this is internal in a solution I should always be able to see the references.

Comment: I also thought about adding the method to the POCO itself but that to me violates what I think a POCO should be which is just a pass through from the Data layer out we specifically call the class this is operating on a Data Transfer Object. The private method on a service class is the second way I thought about doing this. This function returns a value and then a lot of other classes will use that value to do a bunch of other things or including display, other logic etc. But then you are injecting a whole other class(potentially) to get this value out of a list which seemed like overkill.

Comment: I would say, look at the bigger picture. What happens when you have more than one way to select the right poco? what happens when this function is reused all over the place and then you want to change it for one particular edge case? You can define stand alone functions all over the place  if you like, but you lose the structure of OOP

Comment: @Stevenfowler16: the third point in this answer, and Ewan's last comment are the drawbacks to this design. This thing is just hanging out by itself with no other purpose than to contain a method that operates on a collection. You might be missing an abstraction: `PocoCollection` which could define the property or method you want, and internally contains an `IEnumerable<POCO>` or `List<POCO>`, depending on whether or not you need add/remove functionality. This new PocoCollection could implement `IEnumerable<POCO>` and you can use that object in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: That abstraction was the second way I thought about doing this but seemed like a lot for the one method I have added to the IEnumerable<POCO> type with the extension.

Answer (score 1):

My litmus test whether to use extension methods - or not - are the following two criteria:

1. One cannot easily add the method to the extended type directly, because it would require changing a library outside of ones control, or add an undesired dependency to the library where the type is defined.

   `List<T>` is part of the framework, so clearly out of your control. But as you said, you could derive `POCOList` from `List<POCO>` and hence create a type which you can extend.
2. The added method "fits well" to the abstraction of the type which gets extended.

   By "fits well", I usually think of methods which are not exclusively supporting just one specialized use case, but make sense for the type itself, often with some potential to be reused in different use cases (at least in the context of the application or system where the extension method "lives"). Note this is also a criterion I would expect to be fulfilled for a derivation like `POCOList`.

Sure, the second criterion may be somewhat opinionated, but the way you described, it seems this is not fulfilled here. Hence I think [Ewan's suggestion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/444646) to place a method in the outer context (like some service) is ok here.

Where I strongly disagree to that (otherwise good) answer, however, is that extension methods are "generally bad". Such statements are quite unprofessional and too dogmatic for my taste.